# Inserir Array no JSON

Tags: javascript, c#, json, asp.net

Tenho uma dúvida, quero inserir uma lista dentro de um campo `JSON`.

Como faço para que as strings que estão na lista cidades passem a fazer parte das opções de cidades para o estado *Gurajat*?

O código está assim:

```
var countryStateInfo = {
    "USA": {
            "California": {
                "Los Angeles": ["90001", "90002", "90003", "90004"],
                "San Diego": ["92093", "92101"]
            },
            "Texas": {
                "Dallas": ["75201", "75202"],
                "Austin": ["73301", "73344"]
            }
    },
    "India": {
        "Assam": {
            "Dispur": ["781005"],
            "Guwahati": ["781030", "781030"]
        },
        "Gujarat": [

            <%

                List<String> cidades = new List<String>();
                conn.Open();
                cmd.CommandText = "SELECT Distinct [nom_Comunidade/Celula] FROM [Central].[dbo].[TBGC061_CR_tbl_Membros_Mes] where [nom_comunidade/Celula] is not null and [nom_comunidade/Celula] not like '%rede%' and [nom_comunidade/Celula] <> 'Células Simples'";
                dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                string x = "";

                if (dr.HasRows)
                {
                    while (dr.Read())
                    {
                        cidades.Add(dr.GetString(0));

                    }
                }
                conn.Close();

                foreach (string ct in cidades)
                {
                    x +="'" + ct + "',";
                }
            %>

            <% = x %>

        ]
    }
}

<!-- end snippet -->
```

Comment: Te aconselho a Deserializar o json para um objeto, com o objeto você pode trabalhar com as listas, adicionar, remover e após isso serializar ele para uma string json, de uma olhada neste [link](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SerializingJSON.htm), acho que é um caminho melhor e mais seguro

Comment: @JoãoPauloAmorim , tenho duvidas de como ficaria o objeto. E aonde eu criaria ele? na própria pagina? Pode me ajudar?

Comment: esse seu json vem da onde? essa função que você está fazendo é no back-end? não tenho muita informação pra poder te ajudar .

Comment: O meu Json está aí, na pagina aspx. Não consigo referenciar na pagina aspx uma classe que criei. Tudo que tenho é o documento aspx. Acima do que eu mandei só tem umas caixas de seleção e a string de conexao.

Comment: Entendi, acho que naão consigo te ajudar, caso você recebesse esse json no back-end por alguma chamada rest ou algo assim seria facil, pois ai vc conseguia passar o json para object, trabalhar ele e apos isso transformar em json novamente

Comment: Não entendi muito bem a tag javascript na pergunta.

Answer (score 0):

Eu não entendi muito bem a pergunta, mas se eu entendi certo você está querendo jogar uma lista no teu Json, recomendo Serializar tua lista em um Json...

`JsonConvert.SerializeObject(cidades, Formatting.Indented);` Isso te retorna uma string já identada, aí é só jogar no teu Json.